# How can one handle data from mapGetters on first render to avoid undefined error of the property to be accessed in vue

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to access a stored array from the store using vuex with the mapGetters helper.
The object is successfully obtained but during the first render, the property defined in mapGetters is not accessed until the API call that dispatches the storage of the object is complete.
This results in an `undefined type error` which causes my view code rendered to break until the stored object can be retrieved.

How can I ensure that the property in the computed section is not undefined or rather can be accessed during the first load of the page.
Below is my store, and Vue code. The `created` lifecycle runs the API call to dispatch the saving of the array object on successful response.

**STORE CODE**

```js
const state = {
    assessments:[],
    assessment:{},
    inspections:[]
}

const mutations={
    setAssessments(state, assessments){
        state.assessments = assessments
    },
    setAssessment(state, assessment){
        state.assessment = assessment
    },
    setInspections(state, inspections){
        state.inspections = inspections
    }

}

const getters={
    assessments:state =>state.assessments,
    inspections:state =>state.inspections,
    assessment:state =>state.assessment
    

}

const actions={

    saveAssessments({commit}, assessments){
        commit("setAssessments", assessments)
    },

    saveInspections({commit}, inspections){
        commit("setInspections", inspections)
    },
    saveAssessment({commit}, assessment){
        commit("setAssessment", assessment)
    }


}

const assessments = {
    state,
    mutations,
    actions,
    getters
}
export default assessments
```

**The getters and computed section**

```js
  import { assesVehicleEndpoint } from "@/utils/apis";
  import { mapGetters} from 'vuex';

created: function (){

      this.fetchAssessments()
      },

  computed:{
      ...mapGetters({
   assessments:"assessments"  
  }),

  completedAssessments(){
    let  compAssessments 
   if(this.assessments != undefined){
    compAssessments = this.assessments.results.filter(assessment=>{
      return(assessment.pre_pre_screening_status === "D" || assessment.pre_pre_screening_status === "C"
      || assessment.pre_screening_status === "D" || assessment.pre_screening_status === "C"
      || assessment.car_care_status === "D" || assessment.car_care_status === "C"
      || assessment.inspection_status === "D" || assessment.inspection_status === "C"
      || assessment.pre_screening_plus_status === "D" || assessment.pre_screening_plus_status === "C"
      )
    }) 
   }

    return compAssessments
  },
 

  }
```

Comment: The error happens in the computed section while getting completedAssessments. It reads:  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')"

Comment: Yeah, I should first check whether the assessment is a truthy value before doing the filter.  this.assessments && this.assessments.results && this.assessments.results.filter(....)